# @Validated not activating validation annotations on variables of contained object

Tags: spring, validation, hibernate-validator, spring-rest

I have a class which has a contained object. I am using common Dto for post and put operations. So using @Validated and using groups attribute, I am trying to activate annotations like @Size as needed by post or put. But the issue is that the validations annotations don't get activated for the variables inside the contained object. They apply only for the direct variables of the dto. Is there something that I am missing on?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing any code at all but I think you are missing the @Valid annotation.

You need to mark the objects you want to cascade to with @Valid (the javax.validation annotation).

Comment: Actually i want to use same dto for both creat and update calls.And both calls can have differetn vakidation for same field of same dto ..like employeeName can be null during update but mandatory during create.with @vakidated i am able to do that.but its not activating the annotations applied on the variables of referenced objects. Say i have address in employee..So street field in address class is not getting validated.

Comment: As explained in my first answer, you need to mark the objects with @Valid if you want the cascaded validation to trigger. See this paragraph of the documentation for more information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-object-graph-validation .